# Cannot use imagemagick to display a picture

Tags: debian, imagemagick, xserver

I use Debian 8 (64bit). When I use imagemagick's `display` program to view a picture, the terminal show this

```
root@procedure2012:/home/procedure2012/Pictures# display hhkb-de.jpg
No protocol specified
display: unable to open X server `:0' @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/426.
```

How can I fix the problem? Is that because I don't have a x server? How can I install a x server?

Comment: Are you running just in the console and using text-based applications maybe? If so, you will need to start your X server, which is probably done by running `startx`.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem. I use my account (not root) log in the GUI and switch to the root in a terminal. So `display` can't use my account's GUI and root doesn't have a GUI. When I switch back to my account, the problem is solved.

Comment: If you want to allow root to use your GUI, you can do `xhost +` in your GUI to allow root to access it.